# Copy Database on Azure without performance jump

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sdk-.net

I use the Azure .NET Fluent SDK to copy a database:

```
        var backupDb = await azure.SqlServers.Databases
            .Define(targetDbName)
            .WithExistingSqlServer(server)
            .WithSourceDatabase(sourceDb)
            .WithMode("Copy")
            .CreateAsync();
```

Under the hood it makes the [following API call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/databases/createorupdate) with the mode `Copy` . It works well, however it gives me a short ~14% spike on the performance graph

[image]

which doesn't happen at all when I run the copy procedure within the Azure portal or with the `New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseCopy` cmdlet.

Is there any reason why the Fluent SDK/REST API call causes this spike? Is there any way to get rid of that?

Comment: I am researching this but my initial thoughts are that the Azure .NET Fluent SDK is making a REST call to your desired database via the logical server, and that task is registering DTU cycles. When you use the PowerShell cmdlet, the copy request is not using REST.

Comment: Can you please type the following in your PowerShell environment and provide those details here: get-host

Comment: This is what we know to date:
The Azure .NET Fluent SDK, the Azure Portal, and Azure PowerShell all make nearly identical REST requests to the Azure Resource Manager API. They initiate exactly the same workflows in the backend. The copy workflow doesn’t restore from a snapshot; the data is sent directly from the source database to the target database, but it shouldn’t show up in the DTU graphs because the resources come from a different resource pool.

Comment: Okay, I assume that was a false alarm. I saw this twice in a row and thought this was a tendency. Now I don't have those anymore. @MikeUbezziMSFT

Comment: If, however, you are seeing a correlation, please collect exact time stamps (with time zone designation) and your instance name and we can look into this more specifically.